# Jquery datapicker and Javascript stop working after adding bootstrap (gem bootstrap-sass) in rails 3.2.12 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

We added bootstrap (with gem bootstrap-sass) to our `rails 3.2.12` app. The format is better. However we notice that all the js features, such as inserting text boxes for new data or inserting a partial form are not working any more. There is no response after clicking the adding-new-fields link on the form. Also `jquery data-picker` stops working as well.

Here is the application.js in rails app:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//=require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

The bootstrap was added at the end and after jquery.

Under `views/layouts/application.html.erb`, there is a line for jquery:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
```

Here is our `application.css.scss`:

```
$iconSpritePath: image-path('glyphicons-halflings.png');
$iconWhiteSpritePath: image-path('glyphicons-halflings-white.png');
$navbarBackground: #555;
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: #888;
$navbarText: #eee;
$navbarLinkColor: #eee;

@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "simple_form.css.scss";
```

Is it compatibility issue of `bootstrap`? How to fix the problem?

Comment: Still have no clue after reading the post above. In which file those lines (in answer) should be added? Is it /views/layouts/application.html.erb?

Comment: Im not sure if it's a typo but you need a space in `//=require jquery-ui`

Comment: you meant a space needed between //= and require? This is the code in our app.